# Which ckan view is required to run fiware-ngsi plugin in CKAN 2.7.2?

Tags: view, textview, fiware, fiware-orion, ckan

I am using ckan 2.7.2.

I followed the process for installing the ckanext-ngsiview in ckan.

[link]    https://github.com/conwetlab/ckanext-ngsiview/blob/master/README.md

But after filling the form and clicking on submit. I did not had any view made
and said

```
There are no views made for this resource yet.
```

So,if anyone can help in this matter.It will be really helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

The view should be created automatically, so something went wrong with the installation of the plugin. There were an issue with version in branch NGSI v2 with new CKAN version since it used the old template mechanism for creating the views.

Can you try with the version on master branch?